# How to retrieve answered messages using Gmail IMAP?

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

As per docs, Gmail does not support the Answered flag on its IMAP implementation. Is there any workaround to determine if a message has been replied or not?

Answer (score 1):

Two things jump to mind:

1. You could look at the In-Reply-To header of new messages to see if they are in reply to your message of interest.
2. You could look at the X-GM-THRID of new messages to see if Google has threaded them together with your message of interest.